# Hibernate : SessionFactory giving NullPoinerException

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am using hibernate for db connectivity with SQL but i am getting NullPointerException.please check the code snippets and help me to get rid of these of Exceptions.

stack traces:
1st exception

```
 java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ")": syntax error)
at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:890) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.8.5-pre1.jar:na]
at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:901) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.8.5-pre1.jar:na]
at org.sqlite.core.DB.throwex(DB.java:868) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.8.5-pre1.jar:na]
at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.8.5-pre1.jar:na]
at org.sqlite.core.DB.prepare(DB.java:211) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.8.5-pre1.jar:na]
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.executeQuery(JDBC3Statement.java:81) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.8.5-pre1.jar:na]
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.executeQuery(JDBC3Statement.java:71) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.8.5-pre1.jar:na]
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3DatabaseMetaData.getIndexInfo(JDBC3DatabaseMetaData.java:1532) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.8.5-pre1.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata.initIndexes(TableMetadata.java:179) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata.<init>(TableMetadata.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.getTableMetadata(DatabaseMetadata.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.generateSchemaUpdateScriptList(Configuration.java:1204) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:212) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at exam.db.SqliteCon.buildSessionFactory(SqliteCon.java:157) [SqliteCon.class:na]
at exam.action.CrudSessionMatrix.getAll(CrudSessionMatrix.java:54) [CrudSessionMatrix.class:na]
at exam.action.SessionRecordsAction.list(SessionRecordsAction.java:26) [SessionRecordsAction.class:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
 11:23:20.070 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL   Error: 1, SQLState: null
 11:23:20.070 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ")": syntax error)
 11:23:20.071 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
```

2nd exception

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata.getTableMetadata(DatabaseMetadata.java:158) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.generateSchemaUpdateScriptList(Configuration.java:1204) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:212) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at exam.db.SqliteCon.buildSessionFactory(SqliteCon.java:157) [SqliteCon.class:na]
at exam.action.CrudSessionMatrix.getAll(CrudSessionMatrix.java:54) [CrudSessionMatrix.class:na]
at exam.action.SessionRecordsAction.list(SessionRecordsAction.java:26) [SessionRecordsAction.class:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99) [struts2-core-2.3.16.3.jar:2.3.16.3]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.47]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
```

sessionfactory creation:

```
 private static SessionFactory sessionFactory ;
 public static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
{
    try
    {
        if (sessionFactory == null)
        {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(SqliteCon.class.getResource("/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
            System.out.println(sessionFactory.isClosed());
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    catch (Throwable ex)
    {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

calling sessionfactory:

```
 public List<SessionMatrixBean> getAll() 
{
    List<SessionMatrixBean> smbList=null;
    sessionFactory = SqliteCon.buildSessionFactory();
    if(sessionFactory==null) System.out.println("-----------SESSIONFACTORY IS NULL-----------------");
    try 
    {

        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        query = session.createQuery("FROM SessionMatrixBean");
        smbList =(ArrayList<SessionMatrixBean>) query.list();
    //  session.getTransaction().commit();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if(session!=null){if(session.isOpen()){session.flush();session.close();}}
        if(sessionFactory!=null){if(!sessionFactory.isClosed()){sessionFactory.close();}}
    }
    return smbList;
}
```

[Edited]
hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <hibernate-configuration>  

<session-factory>  
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>    
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>  
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:/home/xyz/Desktop/xyz.sqlite</property>  
    <property name="connection.username"></property>  
    <property name="connection.password"></property>  

    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.sqlite.JDBC</property>  

    <mapping class="exam.bean.SessionMatrixBean" />   
</session-factory>
```

PS:it's working on ddlauto create

Comment: post your hibernate.cfg.xml also

Comment: And your console log with everything turned to the maximum?

Comment: Is this really correct : <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:/home/xyz/Desktop/xyz.sqlite</property> ?

Comment: Yes connection url is correct,it is working on ddlauto create

Comment: if you guys dont know the answer at least upvote the question ,so that someone else can help me out.